# Is there any way that this function can be a Weibull distribution?

Tags: survival, weibull-distribution

I am currently working on a fatigue life analysis using an old airworthiness standard, Defence Standard 00-970, which was issued by the UK Minister of Defence for British designed military aircraft. At one point in this standard it says "The curves were drawn using the ... a conventional four-parameters Weibull equation of the form

$ S=S_{\mathrm{inf}}\left(1+\dfrac{A}{(N+G)^m}\right) $

where

$ S =$ stress,

$ S_{\mathrm{inf}}=$ stress at infinite life,

$ A=$ numerical constant,

$G =$ numerical constant governing low endurances,

$m=$ numerical exponent."

Upon showing this standard to a mathematician friend of mine he told me that there was no way that the above function is a Weibull function. Having a look around myself I can't find any evidence that he's wrong but I'm surprised that the standard has an error in it. So my question is has anyone here seen the above equation been referred to as a Weibull equation and if so where?

Comment: When was this standard printed? I believe Weibull did a lot more than come up with a single distribution, and he certainly worked on stress of materials. It's very possible that they are quoting a different equation from Dr. Weibull.

Comment: The standard was first issued in 1918 under a different name, it was then reissued in 1924, and then under its current name in 1959, 1983, 1999, 2003 and 2006. The safe life method this equation comes from dates from the 1950s so it is possible the equation was entered in the 1959 version and never updated.

Comment: Interesting. The Weibull distribution was published in 1951 (well, to be accurate, it was first published *by Weibull*. It actually appeared several years earlier, but not from Weibull). I suspect that this may refer to other work from Weibull. I have found [other papers](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/7395291_On_the_use_of_Weibull_function_for_the_discernment_of_drug_release_mechanisms) that refer to the Weibull Function as $M_t/M_{\infty} = kt^n$, but I'm not sure what that's about. With enough creativity, those functions look similar.